# Won't be able to set an Alert

Tags: android

I have used [the library](https://github.com/code-troopers/android-betterpickers) to set a time with the help of a radial clock and want to set an alert at that selected time.I have used AlarmManager to do that.But no alert is there after selecting the time.

**AlarmReceiver.java**

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    // For our recurring task, we'll just display a message
    Toast.makeText(context, "I'm running", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

}

**DeviceBootReceiver.java**

```
public class DeviceBootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED")) {
        /* Setting the alarm here */

        Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, alarmIntent, 0);

        AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        int interval = 1000;

        manager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), interval, pendingIntent);

        Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm Set", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

}

**SiteDetailsActivity.java**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_site_details);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    setTitle("Site Details");

    initComponent();

    /* Retrieve a PendingIntent that will perform a broadcast */
    Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(SiteDetailsActivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(SiteDetailsActivity.this, 0, alarmIntent, 0);
}

public void clickAlert(View view)
{
    alertBtn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    alertGrnBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    RadialTimePickerDialogFragment rtpd = new RadialTimePickerDialogFragment()
            .setOnTimeSetListener(SiteDetailsActivity.this)
            .setForced24hFormat();
    rtpd.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), FRAG_TAG_TIME_PICKER);
}

@Override
public void onTimeSet(RadialTimePickerDialogFragment dialog, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
    startAtSelectedTime(hourOfDay,minute);
}

public void startAtSelectedTime(int hr,int min) {
    AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hr);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, min);

    /* Repeating on every 10 minutes interval */
    manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
            1000 * 60 * 10, pendingIntent);
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

*Permission*

```
<!-- Permission to start Alarm on device reboot -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
```

Comment: your api level on which you are testing ?

Answer (score 0):

With `setInexactRepeating()`, you have to use one of the `AlarmManager` interval
 constants.In this case, `AlarmManager.INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES` because this is the minimum ,you can confirm this from [docs](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html) plus this is available on API 19 or prior.

```
alarmMgr.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(),
        AlarmManager.INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES, pendingIntent);
```

The Alternative is

```
alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(),
        interval, pendingIntent);
```